# Why aren't Java weak references counted as references during garbage collection?

Tags: java

Why are Java weak references not counted as references with respect to garbage collection?

Comment: What is the actual question? Weak references are not counted, so objects will be cleaned at gcTime when the only references that are left are weak. I frequently use weak references for Listener lists in Swing components, which are a perpetual PITA to clean up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because that is simply its purpose.

An object is garbage collected if 0 references are pointing at it. Since a weak reference should not, on its own, prevent an object from being garbage collected, it is not counted during GC.

Have a look at the various definitions of ***Reachability*** to get a clear picture:

- [Package java.lang.ref Description: Reachability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability)

Answer (score 4):

Weak references are not counted as references under GC because that is the whole point of their existence and their definition: references that do not cause the object they point to to be considered live.

This is very useful because it lets you maintain relationships among objects which automatically go away when you are no longer interested in those objects.

You can extend objects with properties, without causing objects to become permanently linked into the reachability graph (turning into "semantic garbage" when no longer needed).

For example, a global weak hash table could let you find all of the `Student` objects belonging to a given `Course` and vice versa: all the `Course` objects belonging to a `Student`.

If a `Student` becomes garbage (you lose all your references to it), the weak hash table will automatically remove the entry associating that `Student` with its `Course` objects.

The advantage is that you didn't have to add a list of students into the `Course` class. And also, when you want to get rid of a `Student`, you do not have to hunt down every `Course` object and remove that student from its list.

Just lose track of the `Student` "naturally" and the weak hash table will purge itself.